# Furnace can’t keep up

Tags: furnace

It’s been at or below zero outside for the last few days. Furnace can’t get the house over 64°.  Blower is running fine. Flame looks good color. Furnace has run non-stop for 3 days now.

House is insulated. Double pane windows. Air out of vents @ 90°, air going back into return vents @ 70°. No cycling issue - blower and filter changed last week.

Right now -3° outside 62° inside. Can it be it’s just too cold outside?
Suggestions?

Comment: You said flame looks good color, which means you can see it. Is the flame cycling on and off or is the flame on continuously, around the clock? If it is cycling on and off, use a stopwatch or a phone app to time how many minutes/seconds it is ON during a 10-minute period. You should answer with a number in minutes and seconds, not a description. If the flame is not on continuously, also describe the air filter: thickness and type (pleated, nonwoven fiber, etc.) or the actual brand and model.

Comment: What region/city/state/country are you in? How big is the house? How many BTUs is the furnace?

Comment: Was it able to keep the house warm last year on days with similar outside temps?

Comment: What sort of furnace is this?  I'd think that 90 degrees out of a forced hot-air furnace burning natural gas, propane, or oil would produce hotter than 90 out of the vents.  Why was the blower changed last week?  Perhaps the installer either put in the wrong size, or wired it up improperly to a too-low speed so it's not pushing enough air.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have -3 F outside, 62 inside and the furnace is running, I'd say the furnace is almost certainly just fine. The problem is some combination of:

- Too much cold air coming in and/or hot air going out of the house. This is generally a gradual problem - i.e., unless you have a broken window it is probably not substantially worse than last year.
- Furnace is undersized. If this was the case then you'd likely have had the problem in prior years.
- Cold snap. If your outside temperature normally only goes to 10 F and you now have a once in 20 years cold snap going below 0, it is quite possible that your furnace just can't keep up.

Can't say more without:

- Location (city/state/country) to get an idea of *usual* temperature vs. current temperature.
- Size, age and type of construction of your house.
- Size (BTU) of furnace.

But if you usually get negative temperatures and you're OK but not this year then either the furnace isn't working 100% properly or you have a new air leak. And if you don't usually get negative temperatures then the furnace is probably just not designed for it being that cold.

Comment: Does "Cold snap" translate to "inadequate insulation"? I'm not sure how else to interpret that.

Comment: "Cold snap" = colder than current implementation of "insulation + windows/doors + furnace" can properly handle. Which can be "inadequate insulation" and/or "leaky windows/doors" and/or "undersized furnace" in a combination that is adequate *most* of the time but not when it gets unusually cold. If the area gets to -3 for several days every year then that's either poor design or poor implementation or something broken. If the area gets to -3 only once every 10 or more years then "unusual cold snap" and put on a sweater. (Well, put on a sweater anyway.)